# WSO2 EI 6.5.0 Clustering with Load balancer

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

**How to implement Clustering and Load Balancing in wso2 ?**

I have ***4 proxy services*** developed on WSO2 EI,

So i need to put **load balancer, clustering** on it to do some testing *(Performance, Stress)*

I have two testing servers to manage load balancing.

I'll be very appreciate if you provide some docs or examples

Thanks,

Answer (score -1):

This [document](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/Clustering+the+ESB+Profile) will guide you on how to cluster the ESB profile of WSO2 Enterprise Integrator (WSO2 EI) with a third-party load balancer (NGINX). Hope this would help with your use case.

Comment: Please provide an actual answer instead of just a link. Consider https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: I have seen this docs, But it did not clarify my probs,
According to this Doc, So should i need third-party load balancer NGINX ?